# What time am I dealing with in Quartz.net?

Tags: quartz.net

I am wondering when I set something like this

```
  Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger("abc", 5, 00);
```

I am setting it for 5:00am. Is this 5:00am server time or UTC time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses UTC time, however this is not properly [documented](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/1.0/html/topic712.html).

**Edit**: actually it looks like it has used both! Versions prior to 0.9 used local time, those after use UTC ([source](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/migration_guide.html)), so it should be UTC as long as you are using a recent version.

Comment: can't find any mention of UTC or local time in the migration guide mentioned above...maybe Quartz.Net moved the doc?

Comment: @w4ik yes they seem to have moved their docs, will see if I can find another copy

Answer (score 4):

5:00am UTC time. Public Quartz.NET API always [expects](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/migration_guide.html) times in UTC format. Just FYI, `MakeDailyTrigger` is just a shortcut to CronTrigger with following format:

```
string.Format("0 {0} {1} ? * *", minute, hour)
```

Comment: Funny, I did not know about MakeDailyTrigger, so I ended up with string.format code exactly as above. I wish Quartz had better documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you enter an hour in the hour argument in the MakeDailyTrigger method that Quartz.Net is expecting local time...Internally Quartz.net converts this time to UTC, but if you enter 5 in the hour argument the trigger will fire at 5AM local time.

Try this

```
        Trigger trigger =
            TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger("trigger",5,0);            

        var ttimes = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger, null, 1);
        foreach (DateTime ttime in ttimes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ttime);
            'ttime is in UTC - so for EST, ttime.Hour would be 10AM
            'however ttime.ToLocalTime().Hour would be 5AM
        }
```

Comment: Just FYI, Quartz.net 2.0.1 does not support UTC time, but this was fixed in 2.1.0. I learned this the hard way.